# how to refresh jquery mobile listviews

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am attempting to refresh a `listview` after I change the list items in it but it keeps failing with the message:

> "Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'".

The list is an unordered list in a div with a `data-role="dialog"` attribute.  The list has `data-role="listview"`.  After updating, if I call `$('#theULInQuestion').listview('refresh')`, I get the error message.  What gives?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of page-events in the jQuery Mobile framework which makes it hard to determine which is the proper one to bind to. I bind to the `pageshow` event because by the time that event fires, the DOM is prepared (jQuery Mobile has initialized everything).

However whenever I am having issues with timing the `refresh` of a jQuery Mobile widget I check to see if it has been initialized and run the necessary code to either `initialize` or `refresh` the widget.

```
$(document).delegate('#my-dialog-id', '<page-event>', function () {
    var $the_ul = $('#theULInQuestion');
    //add your rows to the listview here
    $the_ul.append('<li>a row</li><li>another row</li>');
    if ($the_ul.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
        $the_ul.listview('refresh');
    } else {
        $the_ul.trigger('create');
    }
});
```

Each of the jQuery Mobile widgets have specific classes that are added to that type of widget. So you can check (after appending your rows) if the widget has the jQuery Mobile classes; if it does then `refresh` it, if it doesn't then `initialize` it.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/urTeW/1/

Note that you can place the conditional statement to `refresh`/`initialize` anywhere in your code, it doesn't have to happen when a `page-event` fires.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to trip a pageshow at all.  I have two pages in this jsp.  Neither loading the jsp nor going back and forth between the pages does the trick.  I tried using pagebeforeshow, pagecreate, and pagebeforecreate as well, but no luck.