# CSS missing on AJAX loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Mobile styles for an asynchronously included div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361705/jquery-mobile-styles-for-an-asynchronously-included-div)
>   [Jquery mobile listview - check initialization is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493215/jquery-mobile-listview-check-initialization-is-complete)

I have a mobile jquery list view and there is a LOAD MORE BUTTON at the end. Everything works fine except that the css is missing on the new results added using AJAX.

**Here is my Button code**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <a onclick="loadmore(this);" type="button" id="showmore" href="#more">Load more..</a>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function loadmore(a) {
    jq("#show_more_btn").removeClass("show_more_btn");
    jq("#show_more_btn").addClass("loading_btn");
    jq("this").css("display", "none");
    if (null == jq.cookie("bp-activity-oldestpage")) jq.cookie("bp-activity-oldestpage", 1, {
        path: "/"
    });
    var b = jq.cookie("bp-activity-oldestpage") * 1 + 1;
    jq.post(ajaxurl, {
        action: "activity_get_older_updates",
        cookie: encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
        page: b
    }, function (a) {
        jq("#show_more_btn").removeClass("loading_btn");
        jq("#show_more_btn").addClass("show_more_btn");
        jq.cookie("bp-activity-oldestpage", b, {
            path: "/"
        });
        jq("li[class='load-more']").hide();
        jq("#activity-stream").append(a.contents);
    }, "json");
    return false
}
```

**Screenshot of correct listview**
http://s12.postimage.org/yd2hsk119/original.jpg

**Problem**
http://s17.postimage.org/81ofaf1bz/got.jpg

**EDIT:**
Listview code

```
<div class="content-primary">   
            <ul data-role="listview"  id="activity-stream">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'activity/entry.php' ), true, false ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php  if ( empty( $_POST['page'] ) ) :  ?>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

**Entry.php**

```
<li id="activity-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>">
<a href...>...</a>
<h3>...</h3>
<p>...</p>
</li>
```

Anyone knows what the problem is ?

Comment: The above link may not 100% answer your question, but with this next link you will be able to do what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493215/jquery-mobile-listview-check-initialization-is-complete/9493671#9493671. This has been discussed a number of time on S.O.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493215/jquery-mobile-listview-check-initialization-is-complete/9493671#9493671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the `listview` like [this](http://operationmobile.com/dont-forget-to-call-refresh-when-adding-items-to-your-jquery-mobile-list/):

```
$("ul").listview('refresh');
```

You are adding the elements to the list but they are not styled by jQuery mobile since they do not have the proper classes and attributes.